# Generating Random Puzzle Boards for Rush Hour Game

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, artificial-intelligence, game-engine, puzzle

If you're not familiar with it, the game consists of a collection of cars of varying sizes, set either horizontally or vertically, on a NxM grid that has a single exit.
Each car can move forward/backward in the directions it's set in, as long as another car is not blocking it. You can never change the direction of a car.
There is one special car, usually it's the red one. It's set in the same row that the exit is in, and the objective of the game is to find a series of moves (a move - moving a car N steps back or forward) that will allow the red car to drive out of the maze.

I've been trying to think how to generate instances for this problem, generating levels of difficulty based on the minimum number to solve the board.

Any idea of an algorithm or a strategy to do that?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Example of Rush hour puzzle]

Comment: How about adding an image of the game?

Comment: Oh, sure! I just added.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.ulb.ac.be/di/algo/secollet/papers/crs06.pdf) will be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The board given in the question has at most `4*4*4*5*5*3*5 = 24.000` possible configurations, given the placement of cars.

A graph with 24.000 nodes is not very large for todays computers. So a possible approach would be to

- construct the graph of all positions (nodes are positions, edges are moves),
- find the number of winning moves for all nodes (e.g. using [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)) and
- select a node with a large distance from the goal.

Comment: This approach ensures that a solution will be the lowest number of moves?

Comment: @Unknown I don't understand your question. This approach means that you completely solve and analyze the problems you can generate from one (winning) placement of vehicles. You will know the optimal number of moves necessary for solving every reachable configuration.

Comment: How can I create this graph with all possible positions?

Comment: The question is not about *solving* boards.  It's about *generating* them.

Comment: @Wildcard In order to judge how difficult a generated board is, you have to solve it. And the answer describes a way of (1) solving the board and, (2) selecting a hard starting position from the set of all reachable positions.

Comment: @ziggystar how did you conclude that there are 24.000 possible configurations? What is the math behind that? :) Where did you pull the numbers from?

Comment: @SimonSondrupKristensen Each long car can be at 4 positions, each short car can be at 5 positions. So it's `5^4 · 4^4`. then you have two cars within the bottom row, restricting their number of positions. This makes it `5^3 · 4^3 · 2 · 2`. You can probably integrate some other special situation constraints to further decrease the number. Don't know how I came to above number 8 years ago. But the result is similar.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be creating it in reverse.

1. Generate a random board, that has the red car in the winning position.
2. Build the graph of all reachable positions.
3. Select a position that has the largest distance from **every** winning position.

The number of reachable positions is not that big (probably always below 100k), so (2) and (3) are feasible.

## How to create harder instances through local search

It's possible that above approach will not yield hard instances, as most random instances don't give rise to a complex interlocking behavior of the cars.

You can do some local search, which requires

1. a way to generate other boards from an existing one
2. an evaluation/fitness function

(2) is simple, maybe use the length of the longest solution, see above. Though this is quite costly.

(1) requires some thought. Possible modifications are:

- add a car somewhere
- remove a car (I assume this will always make the board easier)

Those two are enough to reach all possible boards. But one might to add other ways, because of removing makes the board easier. Here are some ideas:

- move a car perpendicularly to its driving direction
- swap cars within the same lane `(aaa..bb.) -> (bb..aaa.)`

Hillclimbing/steepest ascend is probably bad because of the large branching factor. One can try to subsample the set of possible neighbouring boards, i.e., don't look at all but only at a few random ones.

Comment: There is no other approach?

Comment: @Unknown There are exactly infinitely many other approaches. What's wrong with this one?

Comment: I am already creating random boards and I am using a BFS algorithm, but I am not getting the expected results... the random puzzles are just too easy, I am not creating hard instances of the problem.

Comment: And still, using a solver to obtain optimally doesnt grants how to create hards instances, any idea about it? Very thanks, anyway! =)

Comment: How are you creating random boards. I'm also adding something on difficulty.

Comment: A function that has as parameter the number of cars, the main car has a fixed position, to allocate each car the position on the board, the car type and size are obtained randomly. Furthermore, I leave a maximum number of iterations trying to allocate all cars.

Comment: Also, I tried to implement a kind of local search to try explores a neighborhood of the created puzleed, but no success.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested about giving running time to the algorithm, but even so it takes too long for getting good hard instances.

Comment: @Unknown Well, I think if it works at all to give good instances I'd only try to optimize the code a bit. And besides that, why not let it compute for a day and get maybe five instances out. Isn't that enough? Just compute them offline and store them away. I've used rejection sampling to create questions for exams. After adding all the conditions to make the problems interesting the rejection rate was very high. But so what, I needed only one question.

Comment: I understand your point. I need to create 400 puzzles in hard level, that's why I would like if it could be faster.

Comment: If could have a way to guide the generation so could be easier to generate in hard levels..

Comment: I've now tried starting in the winning configuration, but no good results too.

Comment: I'll give a second answer with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient but I recently had to deal with a similar problem so maybe this could help.

1. Constructing instances by applying random operators from a terminal state (i.e., reverse) will not work well. This is due to the symmetry in the state space. On average you end up in a state that is too close to the terminal state.
2. Instead, what worked better was to generate initial states (by placing random cars on the grid) and then to try to solve it with some bounded heuristic search algorithm such as *IDA** or *branch and bound*. If an instance cannot be solved under the bound, discard it.
3. Try to avoid *A**. If you have your definition of what you mean is a "hard" instance (I find 16 moves to be pretty difficult) you can use *A** with a pruning rule that prevents expansion of nodes *x* with *g(x)+h(x)>T* (*T* being your threshold (e.g., 16)).
4. **Heuristics function** - Since you don't have to be optimal when solving it, you can use any simple inadmissible heuristic such as number of obstacle squares to the goal. Alternatively, if you need a stronger heuristic function, you can implement a manhattan distance function by generating the entire set of winning states for the generated puzzle and then using the minimal distance from a current state to any of the terminal state.